# Capsized ship or boat

Tags: etymology

When a boat or ship sinks after turning over its sides we say it capsized.

How did this word originate? The meaning seems little to do either with a cap or its size or tailoring a cap to a size or shape, etc.

EDIT1:

*Cap* is also related to Sanskrit  *Caphala* for head,I could guess the first part. But   addition of *size" got too distorted in usage I cannot understand how, seems to me too far fetched.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [The Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=capsize):

> **capsize** *(v.)*
>   1780 (transitive); 1792 (intransitive), a nautical word of obscure origin, perhaps *(as Skeat suggests)* from Spanish **capuzar** *"to sink by the head,"* from **cabo** *"head,"* from Latin **caput** *(see **capitulum**)*. For sense, compare French **chavirer** *"to capsize, upset,"* **faire capot** *"capsize;"* **Provençal cap virar** *"to turn the head."* Related: **Capsized**; **capsizing**.